How to use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum value of $x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ subject to the constraint $3x+2y=12$
This question is so weird that I think it may lack some other conditions, otherwise it can't be solved. Below is my work:

Calculate the $\nabla f$
$$
f_x = \frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}y^{\frac{2}{3}} \\
f_y = \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{3}}
$$
Calculate the $\nabla g$
$$
g_x = 3 \\
g_y = 2
$$
Applying the Lagrange multiplier method $\nabla f = \lambda\nabla g$
$$
\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}y^{\frac{2}{3}} = 3\lambda \\
\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{3}} = 2\lambda
$$
Solving these equations
$$
\frac{1}{9}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}y^{\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{3}} (=\lambda)
$$
we will get $y=3x$
Substituting $y=3x$ into either one of the equations in point 3 and solving for $\lambda$, we will get $\lambda = 3^{-\frac{4}{3}}$

Until now, seems that substituting both $\lambda$ and $y=3x$ into either one of the equations in point 3 won't enable me to solve for $x$ and $y$ since they will be cancelled off.

Can you show all your work? From setting up the Lagrangian to differentiating and trying to solve the equations? This would be more constructive.

okie, I try to add all of that.

Why use LaGrange multipliers at all?  Instead, simply maximize $$x \times \left( ~\frac{12 - 3x}{2} ~\right)^2.$$  This is based on the idea that $~f(a) = a^3~$ is a strictly increasing function.

Thanks for your comment. But in the question it specifies that I must use the Lagrange Multipler method. thanks!

You probably forgot the constrain, try use it

Substitute $y=3x$ into the constraint given. That should solve both $x,y$.

Remember Lagrangian multipliers asserts $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ AND $g = 0$. It’s a system of equations.

Use $x = X^3, y = Y^3$ instead, then the stationary conditions read
$$
\cases{
Y^2+9\lambda X^2=0\\
2X Y + 6\lambda Y^2=0\\
3X^3 + 2 Y^3 = 12
}
$$
then
$$
\frac{Y^2}{9X^2}=\frac{2X Y}{6Y ^2}=\frac{2X}{6Y}\Rightarrow Y^3=3 X^3
$$
etc.

Cubic function is monotonically increasing. The problem is equivalent to
maximize $xy^2$, subject to $3x+2y-12=0$. The Lagrangian function is
$L = xy^2 -\lambda(3x+2y-12)$.
Setting the gradient to zero, we have
$L{\prime}_x = y^2 -3\lambda = 0,\,\,L{\prime}_y = 2y -2\lambda = 0$.
Hence, $y^2-3y=0 \implies y^* = 3, x^* = 2$.
